# Flutter pub upgrade not updating dependencies in pubsec.yaml

Tags: flutter

when I run flutter pub upgrade, all my dependencies are updating but not in the pubspec.yaml for exemple :

firebase_core 2.3.0 in console but in pubspec firebase_core 2.2.0

Does someone know why ?

Comment: are you using vs code?

Answer (score 1):

try to use `flutterfire update`  write it in the terminal, That's will update all firebase plugins , in pubspec.yaml file.